# Condition to be a prewellordering.

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I'm trying to do the problem 7.17 on th book *Notes of Set Theory* of Moschovakis.

First I will define what is a *prewellordering*:

> A prewellordering on a set $A$ is any relation  $(\lesssim) ⊆ A×A$
>   which is reflexive, transitive, connected (total) and grounded.
>   “Connected” means that any two points in $A$ are comparable,
>   $$(\forall x, y \in A)[x  y \vee y  x],$$ and “grounded” means that
>   every non-empty $X ⊆ A$ has a $\lesssim$ -least member, $$(\forall X ⊆ A,X = \emptyset)(\exists x \in X)(∀y \in X)[x  y].$$ A
>   prewellordering would be a wellordering, if only it were
>   antisymmetric.

I have to prove that

> A relation  $\lesssim ⊆ A \times A $ is a prewellordering if and only
>   if there exists a well ordered set $(U,≤_{U})$ and a surjection 
>   $\pi: A \longrightarrow U$ such that $$x \lesssim y
> > \Longleftrightarrow \pi(x) ≤_{U} \pi(y) (x, y ∈ A).$$

So, here is my approach. I think that if le relation is a prewellordering maybe we can construct a trivial surjection such as $\pi(x)=\emptyset \forall x$. The set $\{\emptyset\}$ is well ordering right?

On the other hand, on the other sense, I think is easy to prove that $\lesssim$ is reflexive, transitive by doind a direct proof and using $\leq_U$ is a well order. Then, the last thing is showing that any subset $X\subset A$ has a $\lesssim$-minimal element. We can take $\pi(X)$, its $\leq_U$-minimal element, $m$, and so the minimal element on $X$ would be $\pi^{-1}(m)$.

Do you think I've maken any mistake?

Comment: I corrected it! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you've made a mistake. If you map everything to $0$, and there were $x,y$ such that $x\lesssim y$ but $y\not\lesssim x$, then it can't be that $\pi(x)=\pi(y)=0$.

The idea is that if you have a preorder, then there is a natural quotient which gives a partial order. And a prewellordering is such where the quotient is a well-ordering.

And the key point is that you need to solve the problem of anti-symmetry. How do you do that? By noting that if you consider the equivalence relation: $x\sim y\iff x\lesssim y\land y\lesssim x$, then the preorder induces a partial order on the equivalence classes.

I will leave it to you to see how to use this to finish the exercise.

Comment: Thank you. I will try by using this relation. The other sense proof do you think is right?

Comment: @Maria: Your argument in the other direction isn’t quite right. $\pi[X]$ has a unique $\le_U$-minimal element $m$, but $\pi^{-1}[\{m\}]$ may contain more than one point. Fortunately, you can easily verify that any $x\in\pi^{-1}[\{m\}]$ is $\lesssim$-minimal in $X$.